# Creating a file inside a directory in my working directory

Tags: python

I created a directory using:

```
def createDir(dir_name):
    try:    
        os.mkdir(dir_name)
        return True;
    except:
        return False

createDir(OUTPUT_DIR)
```

Now I want to create a file for writing and place it inside my newly created directory, that is inside `OUTPUT_DIR`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the python built-in function [open()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) to create a file object.

```
import os

f = open(os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'file.txt'), 'w')
f.write('This is the new file.')
f.close()
```

Comment: It is better to use `os.path.join` than `+ '/' +`.

Answer (score 3):

```
new_file_path = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'mynewfile.txt')

with open(new_file_path, 'w') as new_file:
    new_file.write('Something more interesting than this')
```

Comment: Why >= 2.7? `with` was introduced in 2.5 (see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)).

Comment: Python 2.5 `>>> help("with")
no Python documentation found for 'with'`

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) it was introduced in 2.5. I can use it in 2.6. In 2.5 try `from __future__ import with_statement`.